# A Key error in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a "Multi-user" program that stores a shop list of items for every user logging in during the time the program runs.To do so I made a function called login_to_user that basically checks if a user has already logged in, and if not, creates a new place in the nested dict var user_database to store his shop list.

```
def login_to_user(user_database):
 username = raw_input("Enter Your username: ")
 for username in user_database.keys():
     if(username in user_database):
         shop_list = user_database[username]["shop_list"] 
 else:
     user_database[username]["shop_list"] = 0 #gives place to new user in dictionary
     shop_list = user_database[username]["shop_list"] 
     shop_list = get_list_from_user()
     shop_list = organize_list(shop_list)
```

But after I try to run a program and enter a test user, I will always get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Shopping-MichaelEX4.py", line 170, in <module>
    main()
    File "Shopping-MichaelEX4.py", line 164, in main
    login_to_user(user_database)
    File "Shopping-MichaelEX4.py", line 156, in login_to_user
    user_database[username]["shop_list"] = 0 #gives place to new user in 
    dictionary
    KeyError: 'test'
```

I read about the key error and never found a solution to my problem. I tried to initialize the nested dict a couple of times in a different way. So far, nothing worked.

I would really appreciate any solutions to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is `user_database`? And please fix your formatting.

Comment: user_database is a nested dict that stores all of the saved store lists by User names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried to do `user_database[username]["shop_list"] = 0`, the dictionary can't find `username` in `user_database`, hence the error.

So, first create `username` key in `user_database`, like as mentioned in the solution below:

```
   def login_to_user(user_database):
       username = raw_input("Enter Your username: ")
       for username in user_database.keys():
           if(username in user_database):
               shop_list = user_database[username]["shop_list"] 
           else:
               user_database[username] = {}  # Create username in user_database
               user_database[username]["shop_list"] = 0 #gives place to new user in dictionary
               shop_list = user_database[username]["shop_list"] 
               shop_list = get_list_from_user()
               shop_list = organize_list(shop_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set property "shop_list" of your new user as you didn't tell your dictionnary that their is a new user.
Your else statement should start with:

```
else:
    user_database[username] = {}  # initialize your new user
    user_database[username]["shop_list"] = 0  # then you can initialize the user's shopping list.
```

Hope it helps